# Web scraping - can't locate element text data-wipe name

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to scrape some open data but I keep getting the error that the element has no text attribute value. Before I tested it on Google where I can easily get text in class with that way. I test it with xpath too, I know "nobr" tag is multiple in html and that's evt the problem but normally that can jump with xpath

```
driver.get('https://www.gelbeseiten.de/Suche/dm-drogerie%20markt/Bundesweit')
time.sleep(3)
plz = driver.find_element_by_class_name("nobr").text
plzx = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/article[59]/a/address/p[1]/span").text
print(plzx)
```

The only problem is to located the text with elements ??? I want to loop through the page elements to fill these columns in pd with it

```
#this was working if I scrape just by one value through page

product_titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('nobr')
for title in product_titles:
    print(title.text)


#i want to save the scraped data later  

df = pd.DataFrame([[name,plz.street,city,number]],columns['business','plz','street','city','number'])
```

this is the part with the information i want to scrape

```
            <a href="https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/cf5182f8-e6ba-4846-a1f2-0d179feb68c4" data-realid="cf5182f8-e6ba-4846-a1f2-0d179feb68c4" data-tnid="162004776014" target="_self">
                
        <div class="mod-hervorhebung">
    </div>
        
        <h2 data-wipe-name="Titel">dm-drogerie markt GmbH + Co. KG</h2>
        <p class="d-inline-block mod-Treffer--besteBranche">
            Drogeriewaren
        </p>
        
                    <div class="bewertungen-anker">
                    <div class="mod mod-Stars mod-Stars--" title="5.0/5" data-float="5,0">

        <span class="mod-Stars__text" style="width: 100%;">5.0</span>

    </div>
                    <span>5.0</span>
                    <span>(2)</span>
                    </div>
        <address class="mod mod-AdresseKompakt">
        <p data-wipe-name="Adresse">
            Geisenheimer&nbsp;Str.&nbsp;70, 
            <span class="nobr">
                65385
                Rüdesheim&nbsp;am&nbsp;Rhein
            </span>
        </p>

        <p class="mod-AdresseKompakt__phoneNumber" data-hochgestellt-position="end" data-wipe-name="Kontaktdaten">06722 40 63 70</p>

    </address>
    
        <div class="oeffnungszeit_kompakt__zustandsinfo--geoeffnet">
            <span>Geöffnet</span>, 
            <span class="nobr">schließt um 20:00</span>
        </div>
            </a>
        <div class="mod mod-Aktionsleistekompakt">
        <div class="mod mod-gsSlider mod-gsSlider--noneOnWhite">
            <span class="mod-gsSlider__arrow mod-gsSlider__arrow--arrow" data-direction="left" data-show="false" data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;:&quot;click&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Trefferliste: Slider-Pfeil-links&quot;}"></span>
            <span class="mod-gsSlider__arrow mod-gsSlider__arrow--arrow" data-direction="right" data-show="false" data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;:&quot;click&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Trefferliste: Slider-Pfeil-rechts&quot;}"></span>
            <div class="mod-gsSlider__slider">
            <span class="contains-icon-route gs-btn" data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;:&quot;click&quot;, &quot;name&quot;:&quot;Trefferliste Navigation-Button&quot;, &quot;id&quot;:&quot;162004776014&quot;}" data-parameters="{&quot;partner&quot;: &quot;googlemaps&quot;, &quot;searchquery&quot;: &quot;Geisenheimer%20Str%2070%2065385%20R%C3%BCdesheim%20am%20Rhein&quot;}" data-target="_blank">Route</span>
            <a class="contains-icon-details gs-btn" rel="noopener" href="https://www.gelbeseiten.de/gsbiz/cf5182f8-e6ba-4846-a1f2-0d179feb68c4" data-wipe="{&quot;listener&quot;: &quot;mouseup&quot;, &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Trefferliste Actionbutton Mehr Details&quot;, &quot;id&quot;: &quot;162004776014&quot;, &quot;synchron&quot;: false}" data-isneededpromise="false" data-cookieinfo="cf5182f8-e6ba-4846-a1f2-0d179feb68c4=162004776014">Mehr Details</a>
            <div class="mod-gsSlider__spacer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either try

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('nobr')
plz = element.get_attribute('innerText')
```

or directly:

```
plz = driver.find_element_by_class_name('nobr').get_attribute('innerText')
```

since the text is the innerText attribute of the HTML element.

Because `find_elements_by_class_name` returns a list, you can't directly use `get_attribute`. You need to write a for loop like:

```
product_titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('nobr')
for title in product_titles:
    print(title.get_attribute("innerText"))
   #print(title.text)
```

Whichever works for you.

Last edit: Same thingwith XPath

```
product_titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'nobr')]")
for title in product_titles:
    print(title.text)
```

Comment: but how can i loop all nobr element text through that page. get AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute' if i use elements with for adresses in plz print(adresses)

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by *if i use elements with for adresses in plz print(adresses)*

Comment: i mean i cant use inner text with ,,driver.find_elements`` that work just to get inner text from one nobr with ,,driver.find_element`` normally when i scrap google i just use,,      adresses = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('class')
     for plz in adresses:
         print(plz.text)   ``     to loop through `google maps and get all shop names or whatever . but here on that pages this doesnt work.

Comment: I added the solution that came to my mind although I am not sure. I hope that solves your problem. Remember that there is a difference between `find_elements_by_class_name` and `find_element_by_class_name`. Former one returns a list and the latter one returns a single object.

Comment: thanks ur code is perfect but before ur edit i test the same with loop still get the,, AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'''' i really dont know why its not work is it eventual something cause superclass for nobr and nobr is too multiple on that page? or is it better to use xpath ? and thanks for the effort

Comment: I added another solution with `Xpath`. I am not sure why the code before edit didn't work for you. I tried to cover all the cases. If any one of them is working fine, you are good to go. don't forget to upvote and accept my answer if you like it :)

Comment: funny by class list object loop not working but with xpath. thanks i can work with that. i get little bit too much text with that but i think thats the right way because the xpath loop dont get an error.